# How to Determine If Lookup Value Is Still Being Used in DB

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have a database table with list values that are used in several other tables. So a given table might have a "StateID" column with the number (primary key) from the "list values" table that represents the string "NJ". So the primary key (integer) that represents "NJ" might be used in several different columns across several different tables.

Now I want to allow the user to delete this "list value" entry, but ONLY if it's not being used anywhere. Alternately, I want to have a sproc that would change this primary key value everywhere it might be used, to some "default" value that will still exist.

Is there a good way to do this? Or would I be better off just accounting for the absence of the key value in my code when I display "NJ" so that it displays a default value if "NJ" no longer exists?

Comment: If you have a proper foreign key constraint, just try the delete the database will then throw an error if that row is still referenced.

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't know if it is a good idea to delete values just because they are not being currently used.  All those nice people and things in NJ might want the opportunity to be represented in the data in the future.

Second, the best way to do this is to design your database with foreign key constraints *every time your refer to another table*.  Then it is easy:

```
delete from t
    where t.value = 'NJ';
```

Then -- unless you have overridden the default behavior -- you cannot delete the row while any other row refers to it.  That is part of the power of foreign key constraints.

Alas, if you don't have the constraints, then the database doesn't know what *could* refer to the row.  If you do, you can check all possible tables.  But, you might miss one and then things wouldn't work so well.

So, learn about foreign key constraints and use them when designing your databases.

An alternative approach that might be safer is to have an `isDeleted` flag in the look up table.  Then use a view that selects only non-deleted rows.  You can see if anything is missing in your typical queries.

Comment: I tend to agree with your first statement, and that's probably what I'll end up deciding (just not letting them delete). But I figured there might be a case where they want to remove an item from a drop down, thus causing a problem when the record is loaded and the drop down doesn't contain the corresponding lookup value. So I thought I'd see if there was a relatively easy option regarding that.

Comment: @StarfleetSecurity . . . If you just want to remove values from a drop down, use a visibility flag on the row.